# xinetd does not load environment variables set in /etc/profile.d

Tags: nagios, xinetd

I am using `xinetd` to serve the output of `check_mk_agent`. I have custom check_mk_agent scripts, some of which are configured with environment variables. These environment variables are set in `/etc/profile.d/set_env.sh`. When I run `check_mk_agent` manually, the environment variables are found, and the custom checks succeed. When i do `telnet myhost 6556`, the environment variables are not found, and the custom checks fail.

My question is, what is a good way to ensure that `set_env.sh` gets run in the xinetd context? I would rather not use `env` and `passenv` variables in xinetd configuration, because it would be annoying to unnecessarily maintain environment variables in multiple places on the same host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file check_mk_agent file, and add the flowing line just after #!/bin/bash:

```
source /etc/profile.d/set_env.sh
```

Save this, and retry.